# Using <div> and names/id

Tags: html

Okay, so I'm coming to terms with transitions but not so with div and naming them. I have the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div
{
width:40px;
height:60px;
opacity:0.4;
background:black;
transition:all 2s;
-moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
}

div:hover
{
width:90px;
opacity:0.9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<center><u><b>TEST</center></b></u></center>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

On a layout this just completely messes every thing about it. Everything else has the transition basically and messes the positioning of stuff up.

I'm thinking the problem is that the 'div' is getting mixed with the rest of the layout, if it is this how would I name the 'div' so that it is single and doesn't change the rest of the layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well using, http://jsfiddle.net you can give us an insight working of your code.

**absolute position** the div and it will not mess with rest of your layout

```
div{
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/upLNX/

I don't know why the TEST is outside the box. I need to know how to name the div so it won't mess with the layout though.

Comment: TEST is outside the box because you has written it outside the div in your code. You should write it like this
    `<div><center><u><b>TEST</b></u></center></div>`
and then add a color in your div css as
`div
{
color:white  //add color attribute for text color
width:40px;
height:60px;
opacity:0.4;
background:black;
transition:all 2s;
-moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/upLNX/1/

Comment: Thank you for that!

Is there a way I can change the div name?

Like where it says;

    div { 
    width:40px; 
    height:60px; 
    opacity:0.4; 
    background:black; 
    transition:all 2s; 
    -moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */ 
    -webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 
    -o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */ }

Have the 'div {' as 'div chosen name {'?

Thanks.

Comment: yes obviously there are two things to name any element in html
**id** and **class**.
you can write in your HTML code
`<div id="box" class="box"></div>`
then you can refer to it in your css as:
**for id**
#box{
    ... your css
}

and **for class**
.box{
}

Google _id and classes_ for more information.